# Does the bootstrap "data-spy"=scroll plugin only work in the body tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found an interesting project that I want to customize a bit and wonder why it doesn't work anymore when I put the data-spy attribute in a div tag. Generally it should work but apparently there is something else to consider here. Unfortunately I can't solve the puzzle. Can one of you please take a look at this?

#### Working example (please use fullsize view to test it)

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav-pills {
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
div.col-8 div {
  height: 350px;
}
#section1 {color: #fff; background-color: #51004B;}
#section2 {color: #fff; background-color: #00318C;}
#section3 {color: #fff; background-color: #008C7F;}
#section4 {color: #fff; background-color: #1C8C00;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="50">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3 col-4" id="myScrollspy">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">Section 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-8">
      <div id="section1">    
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <p>Scroll down and note how the section on the left updates.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section2"> 
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p>Keep scrolling.</p>
        </div>        
        <div id="section3">         
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
            <p>Stuff related to section 3. Scroll down again.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section4">         
            <h1>Section 4</h1>
            <p>Final section stuff. The navbar on the left is also on section 4.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Not Working

The numbers not animate (resizing) again.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav-pills {
  top: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
div.col-8 div {
  height: 350px;
}
#section1 {color: #fff; background-color: #51004B;}
#section2 {color: #fff; background-color: #00318C;}
#section3 {color: #fff; background-color: #008C7F;}
#section4 {color: #fff; background-color: #1C8C00;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
 <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="50">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3 col-4" id="myScrollspy">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">Section 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-8">
      <div id="section1">    
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <p>Scroll down and note how the section on the left updates.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section2"> 
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <p>Keep scrolling.</p>
        </div>        
        <div id="section3">         
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
            <p>Stuff related to section 3. Scroll down again.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section4">         
            <h1>Section 4</h1>
            <p>Final section stuff. The navbar on the left is also on section 4.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```